# How to "horizontalize" multiple lines in oracle

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have a table with this content:

| date | user | id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11MAR23 | a1 | 10 | 1024 |
| 11MAR23 | a1 | 20 | 510 |
| 11MAR23 | a1 | 40 | 788 |
| 11MAR23 | a2 | 20 | 300 |
| 12MAR23 | a1 | 30 | 400 |

and my outcome table should look like this:

| date | user | id10 | id20 | id30 | id40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11MAR23 | a1 | 1024 | 510 |  | 788 |
| 11MAR23 | a2 |  | 300 |  |  |
| 12MAR23 | a1 |  |  | 400 |  |

the columns are hard coded, no changes anticipated. Just the count of the id´s should be shown in one line instead of multiple lines.

I tried with partitioning, but it displays in different lines like this:

| date | user | id10 | id20 | id30 | id40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11MAR23 | a1 | 1024 |  |  |  |
| 11MAR23 | a1 |  | 510 |  |  |

... and so forth ...

Thanks again for your help.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collapse the rows using aggregation, such as MAX or SUM, and use DECODE or CASE to selectively decide what to include in each column, like this:

```
SELECT date,
       usr,
       SUM(DECODE(id,10,count,0)) id10,
       SUM(DECODE(id,20,count,0)) id20,
       SUM(DECODE(id,30,count,0)) id30,
       SUM(DECODE(id,40,count,0)) id40
  FROM table
 GROUP BY date,
          usr
```

OR

```
SELECT date,
       usr,
       MAX(DECODE(id,10,count)) id10,
       MAX(DECODE(id,20,count)) id20,
       MAX(DECODE(id,30,count)) id30,
       MAX(DECODE(id,40,count)) id40
  FROM table
 GROUP BY date,
          usr
```

Except don't use COUNT or DATE as column names, they are reserved keywords.

Comment: Thanks a million, thats exactly what I searched for.